# How to make text appear when mouse hovers over an area?

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a simple dashboards in which the range of the sliderInput is restricted. To explain why it is restricted I would like a text(box) to appear when the mouse hovers over the restricted area. Is there a simple way to do this?

So far, I have only found information about text hovers in plots and graphs.

```
sliderInput2 <- function(inputId, label, min, max, value, step=NULL, from_min, from_max){
  x <- sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step)
  x$children[[2]]$attribs <- c(x$children[[2]]$attribs, 
                               "data-from-min" = from_min, 
                               "data-from-max" = from_max)
  x
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput2("slider", "Slide:",
               min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1, from_min = 0.2, from_max = 0.8
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the code above is ran, the slider can only be used from 0.2 to 0.8. When it is tried to set at for example 0.9 or when the mouse hovers over that area, I would like some text to appear. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library shinyBS allows this:

[shinyBS](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Tooltips_and_Popovers.html)

For your example, see updated code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

sliderInput2 <- function(inputId, label, min, max, value, step=NULL, from_min, from_max){
  x <- sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step)
  x$children[[2]]$attribs <- c(x$children[[2]]$attribs, 
                               "data-from-min" = from_min, 
                               "data-from-max" = from_max)
  x
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput2("slider", "Slide:",
               min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1, from_min = 0.2, from_max = 0.8
  ),
  bsTooltip("slider", "HoverOnMe", placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover",
            options = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a `div` and provide a title or use `bsTooltip`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

sliderInput2 <- function(inputId, label, min, max, value, step=NULL, from_min, from_max){
  x <- sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step)
  x$children[[2]]$attribs <- c(x$children[[2]]$attribs, 
                               "data-from-min" = from_min, 
                               "data-from-max" = from_max)
  x
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(
    title="My title", 
    sliderInput2("slider", "Slide:", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1, from_min = 0.2, from_max = 0.8)
  ),
  sliderInput2("slider2", "Slide:", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1, from_min = 0.2, from_max = 0.8),
  bsTooltip(id = "slider2", title = "My hover text", placement = "right", trigger = "hover")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```